# In ACID is C the responsibility of the DBMS implementation?

Tags: database, transactions, rdbms, consistency, acid

I am confused on the very concept of ACID.
All references/textbooks describe ACID as a set of properties that the database system is expected/required to maintain in order to preserve data integrity.
But the C part of ACID i.e. Consistency does not really seem to actually be a responsibility of the database.
In some references (e.g. Silberschatz) in the sense that the code itself of a transaction (if run in isolation) lefts the database in consistent state i.e. the transaction code is correct and hence this is the application's programmer's perspective not of the DBMS.
And in other references the description is vague like "leaving the database in consistent state"
So which is correct?

Comment: All the letters of ACID are the responsibility of the database: Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability,.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:Please see my last 2 comments in the answer or Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In transactions, the technical term *consistent* means "satisfying all known integrity constraints".

By definition, integrity constraints are declared to the dbms, and are expected to be enforced by the dbms. Why? Because if application programmers were responsible, every application programmer *might* make a different decision about what constitutes a consistent update operation.

For example, one application programmer might decide that every unit price that's more than $10,000 is in error. Another application programmer might decide that every unit price that's more than $12,000 is in error--but that $11,000 is a valid unit price.  One programmer's work will accept a unit price of $11,000; the other's will kick it out as an error.

Relational databases resolve that inconsistency by centralizing decisions about unit prices. In this particular case, that decision might be centralized in the form of a CHECK() constraint on the "unit_price" column. Once that integrity constraint is in place, every update operation will result in a consistent value in the "unit_price" column. It doesn't matter

- how many application programmers there are,
- how well (or how poorly) trained they are,
- how many different applications there are,
- what languages they're written in,
- whether the sleep-deprived DBA is executing an update from a command-line console.

All those update operations will find it impossible to set the "unit_price" column to a value fails to satisfy all the known integrity constraints. That means all those update operations will result in a state that *satisfies* all the known integrity constraints. That's the definition of *consistent*.

---

- In the relational model, *integrity constraints* and *business rules* mean the same thing.<sup>1</sup> Some people use *business rules* to mean something else; you have to determine their meaning by careful reading.
- Integrity constraints (or business rules) should *never* be under the control of end users if your data is important. Constraints can easily be changed by a DBA, usually with a single SQL statement. But knowing *which* statement to execute and *when* to execute it is not in most end user's skill set.
- The terms *consistent* and *correct* mean two different things. A database state can be consistent without being correct. A unit price that is within the range of a CHECK() constraint might still be the wrong price, a person's name might be misspelled, etc.
- Neither the relational model nor the SQL standards are defined by a particular SQL implementation. They're *especially* not defined by MySQL's behavior, which is just barely SQL. (CHECK constraints parsed but not enforced, indeterminate results using GROUP BY, no analytic functions, nonstandard quoting in backticks, etc.)

---

If I had *Database System Concepts* in front of me, and I wanted to understand what the author meant by "Ensuring consistency for an individual transaction is the responsibility of the programmer who codes the transaction.", I'd ask myself these questions.

- Is there any errata that refers to the section in question?
- What does the author say about ACID properties in earlier editions? In later editions?
- Does the author distinguish *correct* transactions (they have the right data) from *consistent* transactions (they don't violate any of the integrity constraints)?
- Does the author *always* say that consistency is the responsibility of the programmer? (I'd say that correctness is; consistency isn't.)
- What programmer is the author talking about? (Application programmer writing a Rails app? DBA writing a stored proc? Hard-core programmer writing the transactional subsystem for PostgreSQL?)
- Does the author *never* say that consistency is the responsibility of the dbms?
- Does the author *ever* say that, of the four ACID properties of transactions, A, I, and D are the responsibility of the dbms, but C isn't? (I'll bet he doesn't.)
- Is consistency of an individual transaction different from consistency of a database? Where else does the author talk about that?

---

1. "Centralized control of the database can help in avoiding such problems--insofar as they can be avoided--by permitting the data administrator to define, and the DBA to implement, **integrity constraints** (also known as *business rules*) to be checked whenever any update operation is performed." *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed, C.J. Date, p 18.

Comment: If an application programmer writes a transaction that commits a unit price which is not correct, in the sense that it is not aligned to **what the business** has decided the unit price has to be, then even if that transaction runs completely in isolation, by itself, then the transaction will leave the database in an inconsistent state.So the transaction's code is wrong and causes this inconsistency.So it is irrelevant to ACID in the sense that ACID are properties we use to deal concurrency.

Comment: The check constraints that you mention in your answer, IMHO are not relevant because these are developer's integrity checks and not business validation checks for 2 reasons: 1) I don't think  business constraints would be applied at the DB level as these kind of constraints need to be configurable by the business users 2) Second and most important not all databases implement CHECK CONSTRAINTS, example MySQL. And MySQL does support transactions.People say that MySQL is not the best solutions for transactions but not because of the missing CHECK CONSTRAINTS (as far as I have read)

Comment: Please do let me know what you think on my understanding of your answer

Comment: I don't *think* you understand my answer. I expanded some points you touched on in your comments.

Comment: Since you posted C.J.Date as a reference.From Database System Concepts  (4th edition) Silberschatz/Korth/Sudarshan p.567: "Ensuring consistency for an individual transaction is the responsibility of the programmer who codes the transaction.This task may be facilitated by automatic testing of integrity constraints". Also from wiki:" The database management system (DBMS) assumes that the consistency holds for each transaction in instances. On the other hand, ensuring this property of the transaction is the responsibility of the user." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)

Comment: May be I way off here but it seems that various resources are not consistent on this term

Comment: Yes; I would vehemently disagree with Silberschatz et al, though it could be a question of nomenclature, and/or p507 of a book I haven't got to look at (and I can't be bothered to find an online resource) is discussing consistency in a different context.  If they mean _'the onus is on the programmer to ensure that the operations done by the transaction will corectly characterize the change in business conditions'_ then they're correct. But, at a deeper level, the DBMS must ensure that the DB is consistent according to the rules it has been asked to enforce, and that's what's relevant to ACID.

Comment: Terminology in the preface to the fourth edition is casual, at best.

Comment: What you are saying is fare, but I posted a second source en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems) I believe that if I spend time googling most of the references are controversial. Am I am thinking in a wrong way here?

Comment: *"Am I am thinking in a wrong way here?"* Yes. There's a difference between *correct* and *consistent*, and not every author is equally careful about language. There's also a difference between a database and an individual transaction.

Comment: I have given you a +1 and I will accept your answer (I don't want to be pedantic).*But* you have to at least admit that the book I am quoting (Silbeschatz etc) is not just any book off the self that is confusing.It is the textbook of choice in most universities in the world and the most referenced book. Feel free to correct me here. So  I can not really explain how such a prestigious book is so "casual" in its language

Comment: The way I'd approach it is too long for a comment. I added it to my answer. You can *probably* email the author(s), and just ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the addition.Concerning: `Does the author ever say that, of the four ACID properties of transactions, A, I, and D are the responsibility of the dbms, but C isn't? (I'll bet he doesn't.)` For A:"it is the responsibility of DBMS" p.567,D:"it is the responsibility of the DBMS" p.568, I:"It is the responsibility of the DBMS" p.568, C:"it is the responsibility of *the application programmer*". Just for the history.But I will follow up on your advice

Comment: I mean in the same sentence or paragraph. It's a significant difference from the mainstream; I'd expect it to stand alone, if the author really means what you think he means.

Comment: There are 4 separate paragraphs for A-C-I-D. The paragraph on C ends the way I mention `it is the responsibility of the application programmer..`

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', you've looked at many different scenarios. I think that Wiki in particular may be referring to the fact that business rules or user defined integrity constraints need to be defined by the user. Do you think that's what it is?

Comment: *Consistency* has to do with whether or not the database satisfies all known integrity constraints. That's clearly the responsibliity of the dbms. If the dbms doesn't *know* of a particular integrity constraint, the dbms can't enforce it--some programmer has clearly failed in some way.  *All* integrity constraints are "user"-defined in some sense; somebody has to write the DDL.